# a q-continued fraction related to the octahedral group

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms, continued-fractions, q-series

Let $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$. If $u(\tau)$ is *Ramanujan's octic continued fraction*,

$$u(\tau)=\cfrac{\sqrt{2}\,q^{1/8}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+q+\cfrac{q^2}{1+q^2+\cfrac{q^3}{1+q^3+\ddots}}}}$$

is it true that the generator of the octahedral group is the continued fraction,

$$\big(u(2\tau)\big)^2=\cfrac{2\,q^{1/2}}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1+q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1+q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1+q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}$$

for $|q|\lt 1$?

Comment: I improved your post. Beautiful cfrac for $(u(2\tau))^2$! Where did you find this?