# Ramanujan theta function and its continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, continued-fractions, theta-functions, q-series

I believe Ramanujan would have loved this kind of identity.
After deriving the identity, I wanted to share it with the mathematical community. If it's well known, please inform me and give me some links to it.
Let $q=e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}$, then
$$(1+q^{2}+q^{6}+q^{12}+q^{20}+q^{30}+\cdots)^{2}=\cfrac{1}{1+q-\cfrac{q(1+q)^2}{1+q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}{1+q^5-\cfrac{q^3(1+q^3)^2}{1+q^7+\ddots}}}}$$
for $|q|\lt1$.
If possible, please provide more examples of this nature, available in the literature.

Comment: This is now the third continued fraction of this kind. The others: [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362128), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363353).

Comment: How did you derive it? You might find this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381070/a-new-continued-fraction-for-sqrt2/1381655#1381655) interesting

Comment: Thanks for the links gentlemen,but all of those continued fractions were established by me.I will post my derivations soon,but as a self-taught mathematician it may be hard to follow my methods,being unrigorous perhaps.

Comment: I second @Winther in that the derivation, or its main ingredients, ought to be given. Otherwise this question will probably share the same fate as the related questions linked above.

Comment: The left-hand side does not change under the substitution $q\mapsto-q$, and the right-hand side does not need alternating signs then. I'd therefore prefer this form: $$(1+q^{2}+q^{6}+q^{12}+q^{20}+q^{30}+\cdots)^{2}=\cfrac{1}{1-q+{\cfrac{q(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}}$$

Comment: @ccorn that's an excellent observation

Comment: No need for rigor. Actually I'd favor brevity. Yet I would like to know the (typically few) essential ideas that led you toward those equations. That should reduce the search space for readers.

Comment: @ccorn: I made use of your version. Kindly see answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify,  what you found is a q-continued fraction for the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_2(0,q)$. Using ccorn's formulation,

$$\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q)}{2\,q^{1/4}}\right)^2 =\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n(n+1)}\Big)^2 =\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1\color{red}-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1\color{red}-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1\color{red}-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}\tag1$$

One can compare this to your other cfrac in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363353/),

$$\frac{1}{2\,q^{1/2}}\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q^2)}{\vartheta_3(0,q^2)}=\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1\color{blue}+q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1\color{blue}+q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1\color{blue}+q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}\tag2$$

They are *beautifully* similar, differing only in the $\pm$ within the square, though <strike>these two identities</strike> are not yet rigorously proven. (*Update*: The second was already established in 2005 by Michael Somos as the cfrac for sequence $A079006$ discussed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363353/).)

**P.S.** [Ramanujan's octic cfrac](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362128/) can also express $(2)$, but I am unsure if there are q-cfracs for any of the $\vartheta_n(0,q)$. (I believe there are, but I'll have to go through my notes.)

Comment: Using ccorn's formulation ,I was able to show that the cfrac is a q-analogue of gauss's cfrac for pi,kindly see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1389966/a-theta-function-around-its-natural-boundary/1390640#)

Comment: @Nicco: This is not really a Ramanujan theta function; Jacobi found it first. But you right, he would have liked your cfracs.  :)

Comment: @Nicco: What would be great is if you can find a $q$-cfrac for $\vartheta_3(0,q)$ as well. Then the ratio of two $q$-cfracs would also be a $q$-cfrac.

Comment: @Nicco: Thanks. I now recall coming across Eisenstein's general cfrac before, and it must be somewhere in my notes. But too bad the ones for $\vartheta_3^k$ don't look similar to yours. Can you modify it so it will look similar?

Comment: @ Tito PiezasIII:I have conjectured yet another q-continued fraction related to theta functions,kindly see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431200/the-ratio-of-jacobi-theta-functions-and-a-new-conjectured-q-continued-fraction#)

Answer (score 5):

I refer to your claim with the sign of $q$ adjusted so that it reads
$$\small(1+q^{2}+q^{6}+q^{12}+q^{20}+q^{30}+\cdots)^{2}
=\cfrac{1}{1-q+{\cfrac{q\,(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}}$$
Given

1. a [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457024/75794)
   introducing a continued fraction formula by Ramanujan with parameters
   $a,b,q$ and making use of some Jacobi thetanull properties,
2. plus [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457985/75794)
   where the formula and the thetanull stuff is applied again
   with other settings of $a$ and $b$,
3. and [yet another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460599/75794)
   where we found and applied the insight that whenever $ab=q$, the result
   can be simplified along the same lines as before,
   this time using the two-argument Jacobi theta functions,

you know what comes next.

But it does not get boring: This one comes with another twist and a slight
beautification.

As usual in posts like these,
I write $q_n = \exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}{n}$, thus $q_n^n=q$,
and I consider expressions with $q_n$ implicity as functions of $\tau$.

I will again use Ramanujan's formula
$$\small\frac{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty - (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty + (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
= \cfrac{a+b}{1-q+\cfrac{(a+bq)(aq+b)}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q\,(a+bq^2)(aq^2+b)}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^2(a+bq^3)(aq^3+b)}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}\tag{*}$$
If you look at formula $(2)$ in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460599/75794),
you may notice that, by pulling out the first factor of the
$q$-Pochhammer symbol containing $q^{-1}$, the identity
can be written in the fully symmetric form
$$\small\frac{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty
- (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty
+ (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
= (a+b)\,\frac{(-a^2q^3;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q^3;q^4)_\infty}
{(-a^2q;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q;q^4)_\infty}
\qquad (ab=q)
\tag{**}$$
Combining $(*)$ and $(**)$, you get the following formula,
restricted to the case $ab=q$:
$$\small\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{(a+bq)(aq+b)}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q\,(a+bq^2)(aq^2+b)}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^2(a+bq^3)(aq^3+b)}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}
= \frac{(-a^2q^3;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q^3;q^4)_\infty}
{(-a^2q;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q;q^4)_\infty}
\tag{***}$$
Note that the factor $(a+b)$ has been cancelled from both sides.
This is important because now we are going to use it for $a+b=0$ by continuity.

Concretely, set $a=-\mathrm{i}q_2$, $b=\mathrm{i}q_2$, so $ab=q$ and $a/b=-1$.
This yields
$$\begin{align}
\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q\,(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}
&\stackrel{(***)}{=}
\frac{(q^4;q^4)_\infty^2}{(q^2;q^4)_\infty^2}
\\  &\stackrel{(P1)}{=}
(q^4;q^4)_\infty^2\,(-q^2;q^2)_\infty^2
\\  &\stackrel{(P2)}{=}
(q^2;q^2)_\infty^2\,(-q^2;q^2)_\infty^4
\\  &\stackrel{(T1)}{=}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0\mid2\tau)}{2q_4}\right)^2
\\  &\stackrel{(T2)}{=}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n\,(n+1)}\right)^2
\end{align}$$
where $(\mathrm{P1})$ and $(\mathrm{P2})$ are $q$-Pochhammer symbol
manipulation rules like
$$\begin{align}
(-q;q)_\infty\,(q;q^2)_\infty &= 1              \tag{P1}
\\  (-q;q)_\infty\,(q;q)_\infty &= (q^2;q^2)_\infty \tag{P2}
\end{align}$$
and $(\mathrm{T1})$ refers to the product representation of $\vartheta_2$:
$$\vartheta_2(0\mid\tau) = 2q_8\,(-q;q)_\infty^2\,(q;q)_\infty  \tag{T1}$$
while $(\mathrm{T2})$ describes the series representation
$$\vartheta_2(0\mid\tau) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_8^{(2k+1)^2}
= 2q_8\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n\,(n+1)/2}  \tag{T2}$$
which is linked with $(\mathrm{T1})$ by the
[triple product identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html).
Those ingredients are the same as for the other answers. Nothing new here.

That's it. Enjoy the formulae with more continued fractions of that sort.

Comment: This automatically solves the conjecture in [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210928/are-these-two-q-continued-fractions-equivalent)

Comment: @Nicco: Indeed. In that MO post, one would just have to flip the signs of both $a$ and $q$ to get the expressions used here. The condition $ab=q$ is preserved under that substitution.

Comment: Ccorn:Surprisingly ,Bruce C Berndt once commented via e-mail that the symmetric form of the cfrac had not been previously observed.

Comment: According to [ABBW85], in Ramanujan's 2nd notebook, chapter 16, entry 11, the sign of $b$ was flipped, making the expressions skew-symmetric. Entry 12 was then the cfrac mentioned in Tito's MO post. This leaves me with the impression that Ramanujan was aware of the possibility to specialize entry 11 to a simpler theta quotient, but sought something more general than just $ab=q$, and entry 12 was the result. I like entry 11 more though, particularly in the symmetric simplified form here for $ab=q$: The corresponding power series for the numerator and denominator converge to interesting series.

Answer (score 5):

In a paper of me and Professor M.L. Glasser [1] we have generalized the continued fractions regarding this conversation. Namely

If $|q|<1$ and we set 
$$
(a;q)_{\infty}=\prod^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(1-aq^n\right),\tag 1
$$
then
$$
\left(\frac{(-a;q)_{\infty}}{(a;q)_{\infty}}\right)^2=-1+\frac{2}{1-}\frac{2a}{1-q+}\frac{a^2(1+q)^2}{1-q^3+}\frac{a^2q(1+q^2)^2}{1-q^5+}\frac{a^2q^2(1+q^3)^2}{1-q^7+}\ldots,\tag 2
$$
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{q^n}{1-a^2q^{2n}}=\frac{1}{1-q+}\frac{-a^2(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+}\frac{-qa^2(1-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+}\frac{-q^2a^2(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+}\ldots,\tag 3
$$
where $a$ is a complex number.

Hence for example

1)  If we set $a=iq$ in (3) and using [2] pg.17, pg.55:
$$
cn(u)=\frac{2\pi}{Kk}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{q^{n+1/2}}{1+q^{2n+1}}\cos((2n+1)z)
$$
where $z=\frac{\pi}{2K}u$ and $cn(0)=1$, we get
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{q^n}{1+q^{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{1-q+}\frac{q(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+}\frac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+}\frac{q^2(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+}\ldots=
$$
$$
=q^{-1/2}\frac{Kk}{2\pi}=\left(\frac{\theta_2(q)}{2q^{1/4}}\right)^2=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}q^{n(n+1)}\right)^2,
$$
where $\theta_2(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{(n+1/2)^2}=\sqrt{2Kk/\pi}$, $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$, $r>0$.

2) From [3] pg.37 we have
$$
\theta_4(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}(-1)^nq^{n^2}=\frac{(q;q)_{\infty}}{(-q,q)_{\infty}}.
$$
Using (2) we arive to
$$
\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}(-1)^nq^{n^2}\right)^{-2}=-1+\frac{2}{1-}\frac{2q}{1-q+}\frac{q^2(1+q)^2}{1-q^3+}\frac{q^3(1+q^2)^2}{1-q^5+}\frac{q^4(1+q^3)^2}{1-q^7+}\ldots
$$

3) For $q\rightarrow q^2$ and $a=q$, we get
$$
S_1=\left(\frac{(-q;q^2)_{\infty}}{(q;q^2)_{\infty}}\right)^2=
-1+\frac{2}{1-}\frac{2q}{1-q^2+}\frac{q^2(1+q^2)^2}{1-q^6+}\frac{q^4(1+q^4)^2}{1-q^{10}+}\frac{q^6(1+q^6)^2}{1-q^{14}+}\ldots\tag 4
$$
we also get
$$
S_2=\left(\frac{(q;q^2)_{\infty}}{(-q;q^2)_{\infty}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{S_1}=
$$
$$
=-1+\frac{2}{1+}\frac{2q}{1-q^2+}\frac{q^2(1+q^2)^2}{1-q^6+}\frac{q^4(1+q^4)^2}{1-q^{10}+}\frac{q^6(1+q^6)^2}{1-q^{14}+}\frac{q^8(1+q^8)^2}{1-q^{18}+}\ldots\tag 5
$$
But $\chi(q)=(-q;q^2)_{\infty}$, $\psi(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}q^{n(n+1)/2}=\frac{(q^2;q^2)_{\infty}}{(q;q^2)_{\infty}}$, $f(-q)=(q;q)_{\infty}$  (note that $\chi(-q)=\frac{\theta_4(q)}{f(-q)}$). Moreover if $k'_r=\sqrt{1-k_r^2}$ is the complementary elliptic singular modulus, then from [3] chapter 16, Entry 24, pg. 39 we have the following cfrac expansions:
$$
S_1=\frac{\chi(q)}{\chi(-q)}=\frac{f(q)}{f(-q)}=\frac{\psi(q)}{\psi(-q)}=\sqrt{\frac{\theta_3(q)}{\theta_4(q)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k'_r}}
$$

Note.
$$
k_r=\sqrt{m(q)}=4q^{1/2}\exp\left(-4\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}q^n\sum_{d|n}\frac{(-1)^{d+n/d}}{d}\right),
$$
where $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$, $r>0$.

etc...

References

[1]: N.D. Bagis and M.L. Glasser. "Evaluations of a Continued Fraction  of Ramanujan". Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova, Vol. 133 (2015). (submited 2013)

[2]: J.V. Armitage W.F. Eberlein. 'Elliptic Functions'. Cambridge University Press, (2006).

[3]: Bruce C. Berndt. 'Ramanujan`s Notebooks Part III'. Springer Verlag, New York, (1991).

Comment: Nice generalization. (3) is given [in a related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406923) as (P) with a rearranged sum for $r=a^2$, but restricted to $|r|<1$.

Comment: [Link to the 2013 reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259345508_Evaluations_of_a_Continued_Fraction_of_Ramanujan).